# Excel 2016: how to remove rows that do not have duplicates in column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have the following table:

```
| Name | Age | Phone Number |
|------|-----|--------------|
| Joe  | 25  | 111-222-3333 |
| Mike | 47  | 888-999-1111 |
| Joe  | 28  | 222-333-4444 |
| Bob  | 27  | 444-555-6666 |
```

How do I remove rows with Mike and Bob and only leave the two lines with Joe? Thx

Comment: Is it going to be a task you need to do on a regular basis or a one time thing?

Comment: I need to do it right away with a single Excel file, but I might run into this issue again soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a helper column with the following formula:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
   ```

   and populate down

[image]

2. Filter on that column, leaving only cells with a value of "1"

[image]

3. Select the visible rows and delete them
4. Remove the filter, there should be blank rows here and there
5. Sort on the desired column to remove the blank rows

This process can be automated if you need to do it frequently

Comment: Thanks, it mostly worked. I noticed that the counts were incorrect (very large) when entries in the name column has angle brackets, for example "<foo>" or "<foo>[bar]". (what I am filtering are not actual person names, but it's not important). Do you know why angle brackets are tripping the counter?

Comment: `COUNTIF` will interpret `<` and `>` as "smaller than" and "greater than". To fix this problem, change the equation to `=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&A2)`